# How to copy date value from a Windows Forms DateTimePicker control?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetimepicker

I'm building an application with C# code.
I would like to give the user of my programme the ability to copy data value from a Windows Forms DateTimePicker control to buffer. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a `ContextMenuStrip` control on your form to do what you want.

- Add a ContextMenuStrip control on your form and set it menu item like this.  Set your DateTimePicker control's ContextMenuStrip to your `ContextMenuStrip` you just created. you can define your menu item a short cut. here i set it to **ctrl + C**.

[image]

Set its shortcut to **ctrl + C** or whatever you want from properties of menu item that user will click on it.

[image]

finally on click event of menuitem, copy your control value to Clipboard.

```
 private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var copiedDate = dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Clipboard.SetText(copiedDate);
    }
```

Comment: My Bad sir I thought you assumed about context menu can you please3 edit so that i can upvot it againg

Comment: @VadimKiselev glad to help.

Comment: I Though OP Only needed year

Answer (score 1):

as per **OP** Request

Put these code on load event

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

in your code, you can do the following on button click event:

```
string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy");
```

set this string as text where ever you want

or if you want clipboard operation that

```
Clipboard.SetText(theDate);
```

Comment: i guess he wants user to copy current date value on control.

Comment: I want to allow the user to copy the date at runtime to buffer.

Comment: means apply ctrl c ctrl v on buffer

Comment: Only one year in selection, not a full date value.